# Determining variable name on runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, string

How do you determine the name of the variable and access it on runtime? For instance, if I had two strings:

```
string A = "This is A!";
string B = "This is B!";
```

And I type A into a textbox, then I want to display the contents of A using a message box.

```
MessageBox.Show(A); //Variable A is retrieved from the textbox input
```

Is this something that is doable with reflections? If not, how can I make this work?

Comment: are `A` and `B` *class* variables (aka fields), or *method* variables (aka locals)?

Comment: Hmm does that actually make a difference? I actually need the above feature for both cases.

Comment: Yes, it does; fields are available via reflection; locals are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand, what exactly your going to get, but you can use expressions like this:

```
    static void PrintVariableName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = "Hello, world!";

        PrintVariableName(() => a);
    }
```

Can you describe concrete use case instead of conceptual question?

Comment: This is basically what I needed. I'd be wasting everyone's time if I put a detailed question on why I needed this feature as the scope of the question would be far too narrow hence, the topic is likely to be closed.